# unable to echo multiple images with multiple variable

Tags: php, image-processing

I am uploading multiple images from a single input and rename all uploaded files. My problem is; I need to display all uploaded images with separate variables

For example:

```
If user upload 3 images, i need to echo as

$upload1 = 1st file name
$upload2 = 2nd file name
$upload3 = 3rd file anme

No of images uploaded (upload number of file)
```

Here is my current code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_FILES['files'])) {
    $uploadedFiles = array();
    foreach ($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name) {
        $errors = array();
        $file_name = md5(uniqid("") . time());
        $file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $file_type = $_FILES['files']['type'][$key];

        if($file_type == "image/gif"){
            $sExt = ".gif";
        } elseif($file_type == "image/jpeg" || $file_type == "image/pjpeg"){
            $sExt = ".jpg";
        } elseif($file_type == "image/png" || $file_type == "image/x-png"){
            $sExt = ".png";
        }
        if (!in_array($sExt, array('.gif','.jpg','.png'))) {
            $errors[] = "Image types alowed are (.gif, .jpg, .png) only!";
        }
        if ($file_size > 2097152000) {
            $errors[] = 'File size must be less than 2 MB';
        }
        $desired_dir = "user_data/";
        if (empty($errors)) {
            if (is_dir($desired_dir) == false) {
                mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);        // Create directory if it does not exist
            }
            if (move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "$desired_dir/" . $file_name . $sExt)) {
                $uploadedFiles[$key] = array($_FILES['files']['name'][$key], 1);
            } else {
                echo "Couldn't upload file " . $_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
                $uploadedFiles[$key] = array($_FILES['files']['name'][$key], 0);
            }
        } else {
            print_r($errors);
        }
    }

    foreach ($uploadedFiles as $key => $row) {
        if (!empty($row[1])) {
            $codestr = '$file' . ($key+1) . " = $row[0];";
            eval ($codestr);
        } else {
            $codestr = '$file' . ($key+1) . " = NULL;";
            eval ($codestr);
        }
    }
}

echo $file1;
echo $file2;
echo $file3;
echo $file4;
echo $file5;
?>
```

I tried this and I get the error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'png' (T_STRING) in C:\Users\logon\Documents\NetBeansProjects\upload file rename single and multiple\multiple file rename\method 2\process.php(43) : eval()'d code on line 1
```

What am I doing wrong? can some one help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the `" = $row[0];"` on line 42 might not do what you want it to do. Because of the double quotes, the value of the variable `$row[0]` will be printed in the code.

The code running through the eval will look something like this:

`$file0 = FILENAME.png;`

Instead of this:

`$file0 = $row[0];`

To solve the problem you could simply turn line 42 into the following:

`$codestr = '$file' . ($key+1) . ' = $row[0];';`

More information about the difference between single and double quotes: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Edit: For the correct names of the files you could change `$_FILES['files']['name'][$key]` to `$file_name . $sExt`. Hope it helps!

Comment: it works thanks but it displays original file name how do i display renamed file name

Comment: how can i display number of uploaded file